# NLP - using negation in basic GATE's Jape annotation rules to remove unwanted annoted words

Tags: nlp, gate

I'm trying to create annotations in a context of "work situations".
I would like to automatically annotate actors of work situations using JAPE rules. I'm using basic rules because I have no knowledge in Java coding. Here is a sample of the rules that I created.

```
`Phase:ActeurIdentif
Input:Lookup Token
Options:Control=appelt
Rule:ActeurId
 
(
 {Lookup.majorType == person_first, Token.orth == upperInitial}
 |
  {Token.string =~ "[Ff]riend"}
 |
  {Token.string =~ "[Cc]lient"}
 |
  {Token.string =~ "[Ss]upplier"}
 |
  {Token.string =~ "[Cc]ustomer"}
 |
  ({Token.string =~ "[Tt]he"}
  ({Token})?
  {Token.string =~ "[Aa]ctor"})
 |
  {Token.string =~ "[Tt]echnician"}
 |
  (((({Lookup.majorType == jobtitle, !Token.string =~ "chair"}
 |
  {Lookup.majorType == jobtitle, !Token.string =~ "[Mm]odel"})
 |
  {Lookup.majorType == jobtitle, Token.category != JJ})
 |
  {Lookup.majorType == jobtitle, Token.category != VB}))
)
:NomActeur

 -->
:NomActeur.Acteur = {rule = "ActeurId"}`
```

The problem is that GATE does not consider the 4 negations I put in my rule. For example "Chair" and "Model" are still identified as actors.
I tried to use macros but it did not work, I thought it was a problem related to the operator (OR |).
Can anyone help me with this. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is related to the OR operator for sure.

```
({Lookup.majorType == jobtitle, !Token.string =~ "chair"}
 |
 {Lookup.majorType == jobtitle, !Token.string =~ "[Mm]odel"})
```

This OR phrase simply means:

1. Give me an annotation `{Lookup.majorType == jobtitle}` where there is not any annotation `{Token.string =~ "chair"}`

**OR**

2. Give me an annotation `{Lookup.majorType == jobtitle}` where there is not any annotation `{Token.string =~ "[Mm]odel"}`

So the word `chair` is valid for the second clause of the OR phrase and similarly the word `model` is valid for the first clause.

I'm not completely sure if it is valid, but following code could do the trick:

```
{Lookup.majorType == jobtitle, !Token.string =~ "chair", !Token.string =~ "[Mm]odel"}
```